# Constructor overload

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

Can anybody suggest what is wrong here?

```
public class Student 
{
    public List<Class> Classes { get; set; }

    public Student(List<Class> classes)
    {
       this.Classes = classes;
    }
    public Student(Class class) 
    {
        //This does not work
        //Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
        this.Classes.Add(class);
    }
}
```

Calling it as following works

```
var classes = new List<Classes>();
classes.Add(new Class("English", "Elective"));
classes.Add(new Class("Math", "Core"));
..more classes to add
Student student = new Student(classes);
```

When I have call like this (only one class to add)

```
Student student = new Student(new Class("Masters","Accounts"));
```

I get error.
Thank you.

Comment: You might want to publish error message here.

Comment: 1. And where is code for class User ?
2. What is your goal? Just not to get rid of the error?

Comment: @MAKKAM - I have published error message within the constructor. //Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @achitaka-san - yes, I want to get rid of error, so I can use the constructor when there is only one class to add.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your overload with Class needs to initialize Classes before adding class. Try this:

```
public class Student 
{
    public List<Class> Classes { get; set; }

    public Student(List<Class> classes)
    {
       this.Classes = classes;
    }
    public Student(Class class) 
    {
        this.Classes = new List<Class>();
        this.Classes.Add(class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the second constructor, you never initialized `Classes`

Answer (score 2):

this.Classes is not initialized:

```
public class Student 
{
    public List<Class> Classes { get; set; }

    public Student(List<Class> classes)
    {
       this.Classes = classes;
    }
    public Student(Class class) 
    {
        this.Classes = new List<Class>();
        this.Classes.Add(class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initalize `Classes` before attempting to add an object to it.